# Why does the size animate and not the text with this SwiftUI view?

Tags: swiftui

Why does the size animate and not the text with this SwiftUI view?
The Text correctly gets bigger and smaller, but the value of the text does not change.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isAnimating = 0

        var foreverAnimation: Animation {
            Animation.linear(duration: 1)
            .repeatForever()
        }

        var body: some View {

            Text(isAnimating > 5 ? "Hello" : "Byebye")
                .scaleEffect(isAnimating > 5 ? 1.5 : 1)
                .animation(foreverAnimation)
                .onAppear {
                    self.isAnimating = 10
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mh good question .. I would guess because animation() only takes view modifiers into consideration, not the Text view per se.