# How to animate switching from one Text to another with swift ui?

Tags: swiftui

I have an array of strings. For example `["Car", "Boat", "Van"]`

How do I anime the changing of the text in the array (which can contain more strings) so that it switches from `Car` to `Boat` to `Van` by blurring transition? And so that it continually loops this?

I already have an idea on how to animate, but I was stuck in switching the text.
I have asked the question on why the text does not switch over here -> [Why does the size animate and not the text with this SwiftUI view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282145/why-does-the-size-animate-and-not-the-text-with-this-swiftui-view)

But I thought It might be better to write a separate question on how to actually switch the text.

Comment: What about this question needs more focus? I see a vote to close it? 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution animating text based on an array. I have used Asperis transition idea from this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60984127/11878069)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var array = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
    @State var shortString = true
    
    @State var currentIndex : Int = 0
    @State var firstString : String = ""
    @State var secondString : String = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            if shortString {
               Text(firstString).font(.title).fixedSize()
               .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration:1.0)))
            }
            if !shortString {
                Text(secondString).font(.title).fixedSize()
                    .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration:1.0)))
            }
        }
        .animation(.default)
        .onAppear {
            firstString = array[0]
            secondString = array[1]
            
            let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: true) { _ in
                if (shortString) {
                    if currentIndex == array.count - 1 {
                        self.secondString = array[0]
                        currentIndex = 0
                    }
                    else {
                        self.secondString = array[currentIndex+1]
                        currentIndex += 1
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if currentIndex == array.count - 1 {
                        self.firstString = array[0]
                        currentIndex = 0
                    }
                    else {
                        self.firstString = array[currentIndex+1]
                        currentIndex += 1
                    }
                }
                shortString.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already selected @davidev answer.  But based on his answer this was what I have implemented. Cheers

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var array = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
    @State var currentIndex : Int = 0
    @State var firstString : String = ""
    @State var timer: Timer? = nil
    @State var isBlurred = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(firstString).blur(radius: isBlurred ? 6 : 0)
        }.onAppear {
            self.timer = newTimer
        }
    }
    
    var newTimer: Timer {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { v in
            let rndTime = [0.5, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0].randomElement()! // I wanted a random time up to 1 second.
            v.invalidate()
            currentIndex += 1
            if currentIndex == array.count { currentIndex = 0 }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + rndTime) {
                self.isBlurred.toggle()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                    self.isBlurred.toggle()
                    firstString = array[currentIndex]
                    self.timer = newTimer
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```